# oracle database modeler missing toolbar

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I am fairly new to oracle database modeler. the first time I ran the application I seem to noticed that my toolbar isnt showing. is there a way to activate it?[missing toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA8T7.png)

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the Logical Model and select "Show". A new window opens up in the middle section and the tool bar should appear.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If toolbar does not appear although doing all steps in previous responses try this:

1. Click "Tools" and then "Preferences"
2. Select "Environment" option.
3. In the dropdown of "Appearence" change the selected option (Usually are 'Oracle' and 'Windows').
4. Click in 'Ok' to save changes.

After step 4 the program will require to be restarted, accept it and when it restarts the toolbar will be visible again.

Answer (score 3):

It is not missing. You're not on the right item(page). Go to the view/subview and open a model (diagram) and the toolbars will appear. The toolbar changes based on the page. You're currently on the home page. Easiest way to see the page is double click on the sub-view and it will open a new diagram and the toolbar should appear.

Comment: wowwww.. how could I miss that? -.- I brought shame to all db admins around the world

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 4.2.0 Build 921, and nothing I can do will cause the toolbar to show up. Somehow I had it up once and was able to add entities. But now I restarted the application and no toolbar. I've double-clicked "Logical Model". I've right-clicked "Logical Model" and selected "Show" (which worked before). Nothing brings up the toolbar.

Comment: Maybe this is a 4.2 beta bug: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3973331

Comment: I'm using 4.1.4.21 and " database modeler" is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Click View
->Go to Drop Down and click Browser
->To the left of the "data modeler screen" click 
   under Browser and click Logical Model Drop 
   down and then Subviews
->Once you click Subviews, click new Subview and 
   then this will create the new view (in the middle screen) along with 
   displaying the toolbar

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On macos, you should double click on the Logical Model tab in the browser. Then check the "visible" box and "apply".